# Maximum pattern length fpgrowth apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run Association rules using Spark Scala. I first create an FPGrowth tree and pass that to the Association Rules method.

However, I wish to add a maximum pattern length parameter, to limit the number of items I want on the LHS and RHS. I only want one-to-one associations between items.

```
    val model = new FPGrowth()
      .setMinSupport(0.1)
      .setNumPartitions(10)
      .run(transactions)

    // Generate association rules based on the frequent sets generated by FPgrowth
    val ar = new AssociationRules().setMinConfidence(0.6)
    val results = ar.run(model.freqItemsets)
```

The resulting association rules are:

```
ItemA => ItemB, {confidence}

ItemB => ItemC, {confidence}

ItemA,ItemB => ItemC, {confidence}

ItemA,ItemD => ItemE, {confidence}
```

But I only want it to return results that have one item on both sides, i.e.:

```
ItemA => ItemB, {confidence}

ItemB => ItemC, {confidence}
```

Basically, I am looking for a way to specify the maximum length parameter in Spark Scala/Spark Java

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@filter(f:T=%3EBoolean):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]) the results:

```
val ar = new AssociationRules().setMinConfidence(0.6)
val results = ar.run(model.freqItemsets)
                .filter(rule => rule.antecedent.size == 1 && rule.consequent.size == 1)
```

Comment: The one big disadvantage is that this still actually searches for them... so we spend time and problematically memory on these associations we are not interested in..